# Reset vector not working though RCHW is loaded with start address in MPC5777M?

Tags: microcontroller, reset, powerpc, bootstrapping

we have been using a freescale MPC5777M controller for automotive application at work. We had discovered a problem with its reset. 
Let me start from the top.
generally we get the startup code crt0 from the compiler and it was same for this controller too, its compiler supplied by HighTec. We use a lauterbach JTag debugger. what was weird is that when we initiated a reset through the deugger the program counter would go to the Boot assist flash section and then doesnt get directed to _start().  This problem was solved by adding the right boot header at the right flash memory address. Now the reset takes place through the debugger flawlessly, but once controller is switched OFF and ON then the code doesn't run (software didnt begin).

Comment: Where did u put your code ? flash memory or ram memory?

Comment: in the flash. checked it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code is executing, it just stops due to the watchdog not being kicked.

The watchdog would be paused by default when the debugger is connected, so it would appear as if everything is working.

When the probe is removed and the device is reset, there may be nothing stopping the watchdog causing an interrupt.